# Compile C++ code on Linux

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, ubuntu-16.04

I have to use the following code: [cSpade code download](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~zaki/www-new/pmwiki.php/Software/Software#toc10) for Windows, but the code is written with Ubuntu's libraries. I'm not familiar with this OS. Then I switched to Ubuntu and I run the makefile inside the archive, but it gives me an error because it can't find the library `iostream`. 
 I found then [how to install C++ on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689722/how-to-install-a-c-c-compiler-in-ubuntu-14-04lts) with `sudo apt-get install build-essential`, but even after that there's the same error.

**What I have to do to solve this and compile the code?**

I add here the code of the makefile if it can be useful:

```
CC  = g++ -DSGI
#CC = CC -DSGI -no_auto_include
CFLAGS  = -O3
HEADER  = Array.h Itemset.h Lists.h Eqclass.h extl2.h
OBJS    = Itemset.o Array.o Eqclass.o Lists.o extl2.o partition.o
LIBS = -lm -lc
TARGET  = seq calcl2

default:    $(TARGET)

clean:
    rm -rf *~ *.o $(TARGET)

seq: sequence.cc $(OBJS) $(HEADER) 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o seq sequence.cc $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

Database.o: Database.cc Database.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o Database.o Database.cc

Lists.o: Lists.cc Lists.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o Lists.o Lists.cc

Itemset.o: Itemset.cc Itemset.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o Itemset.o Itemset.cc

Array.o: Array.cc Array.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o Array.o Array.cc

Eqclass.o: Eqclass.cc Eqclass.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o Eqclass.o Eqclass.cc

HashTable.o: HashTable.cc HashTable.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o HashTable.o HashTable.cc

ext.o: ext.cc ext.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o ext.o ext.cc

extl2.o: extl2.cc extl2.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o extl2.o extl2.cc

partition.o: partition.cc partition.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o partition.o partition.cc

calcl2: partition.o calcdb.o calcl2.cc partition.h calcl2.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o calcl2 partition.o calcdb.o calcl2.cc $(LIBS)

calcdb.o: calcdb.cc calcdb.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o calcdb.o calcdb.cc
```

Comment: What is the exact, not yours interpreted error message?

Comment: That Makefile looks really weird. I wouldn’t trust it too much.

Comment: I don't know if it's a problem of the makefile or not. I also tried to create a simple .cc file including iostream and a simple std::cout, same issue. Is it possible that I forgot to configure/download something?

Comment: `iostream` is not a library, but an include file (header file). If you installed `build-essential`, this should also install `g++`, which in turn depends on `libstdc++-6-dev`, which includes `/usr/include/c++/6/iostream`, so the file should be there. Did the installation of `build-essential` succeed?

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I did again the installation and the compilation works fine. I have other troubles, but I think they're related to the implementation of the cSpade code.

Answer (score -2):

To compile all .c++ files in single shot.Use this, "**g++ -std=c++0x *.cpp**".Make sure your all .cpp files are in single folder. Then only use this command on Terminal.

Comment: No. Don’t do that. Set up a build system, be it Make or something else.

Comment: Please brief your answer. what exactly setting up a build system

Comment: The questioner already has a Makefile, we should help them get it to work.